# Manipulating an image on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, image-manipulation

I'm trying to draw text to an image from Java in the Google App engine, but I've found no methods (since the java.awt.image.* isn't whitelisted) to do it with. I'm also trying to "layer" one image on top of another, which I can't figure out how to do.

Is there any way to draw text on an image or overlay one image over another in App Engine using Java? Has anyone found any other solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Google's Images API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview.html) instead.

Not sure if it can do all you need it to, but it does include image composition.

Comment: It can't add text or overlay one image over another from what I've seen of it, though I could be wrong.

Comment: You can combine two or more images using the `composite` method: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService.html

Comment: There's a limit of 16 images that could be composited on a single call though, and compositing letter image one-by-one to form long text image would be horribly expensive.